# can i change value of drop down using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Here I have disabled these two dropdowns I make them enable on select event of datepicker
my code is like this

```
onSelect: function(any){
  $('#hh').prop('disabled',false);
  $('#mm').prop('disabled',false);
},
```

now i need that if any person click on `datepicker` again value of both drop-downs should be 00 again is it possible???

Comment: Try `$('#mm').prop('disabled',false).val('00')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#hh option[value='00']").prop('selected', true)
```

*I tried and I found the solution..*

Answer (score 0):

check it [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/euEbA/)

**Html**;

```
 <select id="first" name="first">
   <option>choose me</option>
   <option value="first">first</option>
   <option value="second">second</option>
   <option value="second">value</option>
 </select>
```

**jQuery**;

```
 var newFunc = function () {
     $('#first').prop('disabled', true);
 };
 $("#first").change(newFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
onSelect: function(any){
  $('#hh, #mm').prop('disabled',false).val('00');
},
```

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/euEbA/2/)